# Python pymongo new connection or session management

Tags: mongodb, multithreading, session, connection

Let say, I have a connection with pymongo to mongodb
Then I use this connection everywhere in multi thread - so I do not have to make a connection every time the system accesses to mongodb

What would happen while a thread working with mongodb and another thread start to access mongodb due to the next request?

I am not sure about mongodb and pymongo features so if I might have to write code to manage the connection or the connection itself will controls the multiple request though.

Can anyone explain?